# How to convert Jsonnode to Blob in java?

Tags: java, blob

I have a Jsonnode object, if convert it to string, it will like following:

```
{"id": "A1", "address":"xxxx", "loginhistory":[{"ip":"xxx", "time":"xxx},{"ip":"xxx", "time":"xxx}] }
```

I try to convert it in to blob, I currently wrote the code as following:

```
Jsonnode node = ....;
String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(node);
String sql = "UPDATE users "
            + "SET info = ? "
            + "WHERE UserName = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
                blob.setBytes(1, s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                statement.setQueryTimeout(timeout);
                statement.setBlob(1, blob);
                statement.setString(2, username);
                statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

I expect `info` is blob but it looks like I update it as string (as the string example I give). Any could teach me how to  convert Jsonnode to Blob?